# Keep webpage from scrolling to top on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I am submitting a form via an anchor tag and javascript.

```
<a onclick="submit_form();">Submit</a>
```

As soon as the button is clicked, the page immediately scrolls to the top of the page and continues the normal form submission process.

How can I keep the page from scrolling to the top and why does it do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your OnClick event to be in the HREF.

```
<a href="JavaScript:submit_form();">Submit</a>
```

Or return False so that it doesn't continue processing the click

```
<a onClick="submit_form(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Definitely use the onclick attribute instead of the href.

Answer (score 2):

You could in the form have a name anchor

```
<a name="name"></a>
<form action="example.html#name">
```

It does that because a form submit is a new page request.